# Mi delete no borra en la relación @OneToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Tengo una relación 1 a 1 de Moneda y Remesa , pero cuando voy a hacer el delete de una moneda o de una remesa , ninguna me borra , no me aparece ningún error simplemente que no se me borran en la base de datos. Las otras relaciones de mis tablas funcionan correctamente. No sé si es porque tengo algo mal en la relación del @OneToOne

***Moneda.java***

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "moneda_sequence", sequenceName = "moneda_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "moneda_sequence")
@Column(name = "ID")
@JsonProperty("id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "FECHA_INSERCION")
@JsonProperty("fechaInsercion")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaInsercion;

@Column(name = "FECHA_MODIFICACION")
@JsonProperty("fechaModificacion")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaModificacion;

@Column(name = "NOMBRE")
@JsonProperty("nombre")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "ABREVIATURA")
@JsonProperty("abreviatura")
private String abreviatura;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "moneda", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Remesa remesa;
```

***Remesa.java***

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "remesa_sequence", sequenceName = "remesa_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "remesa_sequence")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "FECHA_INSERCION")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaInsercion;

@Column(name = "FECHA_MODIFICACION")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime fechaModificacion;

private Integer tipoDoc;
private Integer entidad;
private Integer oficina;
private Integer referencia;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "moneda_id", nullable = true)
private Moneda moneda;
```

Mi método para eliminar monedas:

```
public void getEliminaMoneda(Long moneda_id) {
        try {
            Moneda m = monedaRepo.findById(moneda_id).orElseThrow(()-> new Exception("mal"));
            if(m!=null) {
                monedaRepo.deleteById(moneda_id); //HERE RETURN NULL DEBUGGING BUT THERE IS A MONEDA WITH THAT ID
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Pasa lo mismo con Remesa , el método es practicamente idéntico. ¿Puede que sea problema de la relación de ambas tablas?

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner la notación @Transactional() sobre el método de eliminación?

Comment: Sí , sigue sin borrar así @Jesus_jbs

Comment: Normalmente una relación OneToOne se modela poniendo el atributo en una de las dos clases (si quieres navegar desde remesa a moneda es remesa quien debe tener un atributo moneda pero no moneda el de remesa)

Comment: Verifique los atributos de CascadeType en la definicuón de la relación.